# Getting a objects to go down to the bottom of the screen continuously in action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

This is my code so far... 1 Item (a square) Will spawn and drop to the bottom of the screen and come back up and drop again... How do i make more items do that. please help. (So i have 6 items spawning/dropping at different locations at different times)

```
}
var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 550;
DangerIN.x = randomX;
DangerIN.y = 96;

var speed:Number = Math.random()*10;

DangerIN.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDown);

function moveDown(e:Event):void {
e.target.y += speed;
if (e.target.y >= 610) {
    // reposition
    e.target.x=Math.random()*550;
    e.target.y=96;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into the [GTween library](http://gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/):

It's made for animating objects in AS3. Here's sample code to replace your example:

```
//over two seconds, "tween" to random x coordinate, and y=96.
function moveDown(e:Event):void {
    new GTween(e.target, 2, {x:Math.random()*550, y:96}, {ease:Sine.easeInOut});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

put all your objects in a vector and add ENTER_FRAME events to all with random  speed value for down fall effect

Comment: This Answer could be improved with example Code.